# Java equivalent to scala.collection.mutable.Map.getOrElseUpdate

Tags: java, scala

I recently used Scala and `collection.mutable.Map.empty` which is very useful as I can create an empty `Map` and use the function `getOrElseUpdate` to add data in the map when necessary.

So my question is simple, is there exist an equivalent in Java ? From the [`java.util.Map` api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), it does not seem that it is possible with a `Map`. I also [read about an `emptyMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) but it do not fulfil the same purposes.

I would prefer to use an existing api than creating my own.

Comment: You should have looked at Java 8. [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) is apparently what you need.

Comment: @orid This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use Java 8, consider using [Guava caches](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). [`Cache.get(key, valueLoader)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#get(java.lang.Object,java.util.concurrent.Callable)) is the precise equivalent to `getOrElseUpdate`, or you can use `LoadingCache` if you always want to use the same function to obtain the initial value.